# Backward and forward seeking issue in Chrome for Video JS

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, video.js

I am using Video.js for displaying my video. It is working fine with firefox and edge but when trying on chrome the video plays but it shows live instead of controlling bar from where we can move the video forward or backward. I have added the videojs CDN as below:

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="321" height="264" data-setup='{"playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>

<source id="vidSrc" src="${vidUrl}" type="video/mp4"></source>

</video>
```

Here is screenshot when the video is played in chrome and firefox:

**CHROME BROWSER**

[image]

**FIREFOX BROWSER**

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what can I do so that controls can work in chrome also.